# average of ragged double two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, average

my homework for my java coding class is asking me to find the average of a ragged two dimensional array of a double 2d array and a integer 2d array. I believe that my code is correct but instead of averaging the array, it's just dividing it by 2. Any help would be appreciated!

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // adds to 22
    double[][] a = {{7.0, 6.0, 5.0}, {3.0, 1.0}};

   //adds to 48
    int[][] b = {{4, 6}, {9, 8, 10, 11}};
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("arrayAverage = " + arrayAverage(a));
    System.out.println("arrayAverage = " + arrayAverage(b));
}

/**
 * computes the average for an array of a double
 */
public static double arrayAverage(double a[][]) {
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j];

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Calculating Double Array");
    return sum / a.length;
}
/**
 * Computes the average for an array of integers.
 */
public static int arrayAverage(int b [][]) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            sum += b[i][j];

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Calculating Integer Array");
    return sum / b.length;
}
```

}

```
run:
Calculating Double Array
arrayAverage = 11.0
Calculating Integer Array
arrayAverage = 24
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

When dividing by `a.length`, you are dividing by `2`, because that is the length of the array `a`.  There are two items in the array `a`: `{7.0, 6.0, 5.0}` and `{3.0, 1.0}`.

To average all numbers in the array, you need to count all the numbers by summing up the lengths of the subarrays.  Declare a `count` variable, and in the `i` for loop, add to it the length of the subarray `a[i].length`.  Then divide by `count` at the end.

Be careful in your `int[][]` average method of integer division, where decimals are truncated.

Comment: what do you mean by a count Variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is what rgettman means

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] a = {{7.0, 6.0, 5.0}, {3.0, 1.0}};
        int[][] b = {{4, 6}, {9, 8, 10, 11}};
        System.out.println("arrayAverage = " + arrayAverage(a));
        System.out.println("arrayAverage= " + arrayAverage(b));

    }


/**
 * computes the average for an array of a double
 */
public static double arrayAverage(double a[][]) {

    double sum = 0.0;
    int count = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j];
            count++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Calculating Double Array");

    return sum / count;
}





/**
 * Computes the average for an array of integers.
 */
public static int arrayAverage(int b [][]) {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            sum += b[i][j];
            count++;


        }

    }

    System.out.println("Calculating Integer Array");
    return sum / count;
}


}
```

You should get the right answer :)

Comment: THANK YOU BOTH FOR ALL YOUR HELP!