# Method that Averages Numbers From a Double Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginning Java programmer and I need help writing this code. Basically, I have to write a method that averages all the values of a 2 dimensional array. The method has to accept a reference to a double and returns the values as a double. How would I be able to do this?

These are the values of the array:

```
double[][] a = {{7.0, 6.0, 5.0}, {3.0, 1.0}};
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written the method skeleton? Can you iterate over the arrays? Count the number of entries? Keep a running total?

Comment: @Lizzie Cam Your problem is that `a.length` is equal to the number of arrays in a, NOT the total number of `double`s in a, as it is a two dimensional array. A nested for loop with as many for loops as there are dimensions is necessary to traverse this in Java. (See my answer for details)

Comment: Break it down:  1) How do you calculate an average?  2) How do you know how big an array is?  3) How do you navigate a 2-dimensional Java array?  Figure those out individually.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Breaking it down really helped. Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [average of ragged double two dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327550/average-of-ragged-double-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another nested loop structure could be made with `foreach` loops, which makes the code much easier to read.

```
int count = 0;
double total = 0;

// For each array in a
for(double[] array : a) {
    // For each value in array
    for(double val : array) {
        total += val;
        count++;
    }
}

double average = total / count;
```

Comment: not sure why this one got -1'd (or why mine did, for that matter)

Comment: @Patashu: Yeah, it seems like someone came in and downvoted the question and both answers. Not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested for loop, as in

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; ++j)
    {
        //do stuff with a[i][j] here
    }
}
```

The trick here is a two dimensional array is an array of arrays, and each of the arrays in `a` can have its own length. So we need to check what the length is so we know how far to push `j`.